# Space before a Title

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, title, margins

I have a title which I want to give a top margin. However, specifying a paragraph spacing **before** the title doesn't work if I don't have a paragraph above the title.

How can I make my title have a margin top even if it is on a new page with no paragraph above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to select the title paragraph and open the **Borders and Shading** dialog:

[image: Borders and Shading dialog]

Assign a white top border to the paragraph, and then click **Options**.  Set the **Top** value as desired.

Now the title text will have a top margin; i.e., it will be pushed that far down from the top of the page.

However, it is not possible to get down further than 31pt.

Comment: If you've found your solution, then the best thing is to post it as an answer here (like you have done); and accept it. That will take it off the Unanswered list.

Comment: Okay, I'll be able in two days and I will.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is to put an empty paragraph above the title. Then “Spacing Before” works:

[image: example of spacing by dummy (empty) paragraph]